# Insert stored procedure data in a temp table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to insert the data of a stored procedure into a temp table like below

```
CREATE TABLE #CustomTable3HTML
(
    ItemId varchar(30),
    ItemId1 varchar(30)
)    

INSERT INTO #CustomTable3HTML
    EXEC SalesDeals.dbo.prGetDealProposalDetail 17100102, 1
```

but I am getting this error

> Msg 8164, Level 16, State 1, Procedure prGetDealProposalDetail, Line 138 [Batch Start Line 1]
>   An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.

I figured this is because the stored procedure already has an insert into clause defined and I found out that it can be used only once in the calling chain.

So I started looking for other options and found out about OpenRowSet which I am using as below

```
 SELECT * 
 INTO #CustomTable3HTML      
 FROM OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB','Server=Demo\Demo;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Database=SalesDeals',
      'SET NOCOUNT ON;SET FMTONLY OFF;EXEC SalesDeals.dbo.prGetDealProposalDetail 17100102,1')
```

I am getting an error when I run this SQL command

> Access to the remote server is denied because no login-mapping exists.

It works fine when I use a higher level account like sysadmin but fails with the other account which is a normal db owner on the database where I am running this SQL.

Comment: Is it possible to make any changes to the stored procedure so that it doesn't need the insert statement? Or could you change it to a view? If you used a view of the tables the stored procedure is drawing data from then you could insert from the view without getting the nested insert error

Answer (score 0):

There is work around of this. It's not beautiful, but it will work.

1. In our outer query define a table:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE #CustomTable3HTML
   (
        ItemId varchar(30),
        ItemId1 varchar(30)
   )
   ```
2. Change the procedure adding the following code at the end:

   ```
   IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CustomTable3HTML')
        BEGIN
             INSERT INTO #CustomTable3HTML
             SELECT ....
        END
   ELSE
        BEGIN
             SELECT ....
        END
   ```
3. After executing the stored procedure you will have the data in table.